# JSTL how to access an array of request paramters in the JSP/view file

Tags: jstl, el

I have a request url like this

```
http://www.example.com/?q[]=a&q[]=b&q[]=c
```

In JSTL

```
@param['q[]']
```

only gives me the first value of the array, which is "a" in this case. How to get "b", "c" from the request parameter? And ideally is there a way to get the reference to the "q[]" array so that I can iterate through it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html#wp71043 (first link when googling for JSP EL):

> paramValues: Maps a request parameter name to an array of values